# character to numeric symbol change error in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a problem with numeric and character values.

I did **proc contents**, so I have variable Poids as characters.
I want to use the following, but it does not change to numeric . best32. is used as it is demanded in problem. Do I do any mistake?

```
data X;
set Y;
Poids=input(Poids,best32.);
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem. I cannot have same variable defined as both character and numeric. To fix this problem, I have to rename initial variable in dataset options as shown below and then drop the renamed variable.

```
data X( drop =Poids_char;
set Y(rename=(Poids=Poids_char));
Poids=input(Poids_char,best32.);
run;
```